# How to dismiss a UIImagePickerController on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a problem with regarding how to dismiss the UIImagePickerController on an iPad. I have implemented a camera with a custom cameraOverlayView that has a button on it to access the photoLibrary.The iPad used the same code as the iPhone version to present the picker in order to show the photoLibrary. However, when I pressed the cancel button it goes back to a black page with nothing on it (the same code would take the iPhone to the custom camera view). Does iPad have a different method for dismissing viewControllers or do I have to use a popover to access the photoLibrary?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
{
    CDVCameraPicker* cameraPicker = (CDVCameraPicker*)picker;
    if ([self popoverSupported]){
            NSLog(@"cancel");
        [[cameraPicker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (isSelectingFromPhotoAlbum == true){
        [[cameraPicker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

The NSLog message did appear on console, so I am assuming that iPad is recognized, but it does not go back to the previous view.

Any thoughts on what happened?

Comment: @rmaddy, right now when I press the button, it will presents the UImagePickerController with sourceTypePhotoLibrary perfectly on full screen. Is that something should not be done? Also, if you look at the default iPad camera app, they are not showing the photolibrary on a popover either. How did they do that?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, here's you should have to do:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker
{
     [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```